# How to pass the parameters dynamically in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Anyone kindly guide me to pass the parameters dynamically in c#. I have assigned two text boxes, where the user inputs in those text boxes have to be passed as parameters. I am getting response from server if I pass static parameters.

Here is my coding.

```
        string AuthServiceUri = "my url";
        HttpWebRequest spAuthReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(AuthServiceUri) as HttpWebRequest; 
        spAuthReq.ContentType = "application/json"; 
        spAuthReq.Method = "POST"; 
        spAuthReq.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), spAuthReq);

    }
    void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult) 
    {

        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState; 
        Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);
        string postData = "id=1234567890&keyword=otp&message=8320926"; //passing static parameters & here i need to pass the text boxes data in id and message field.
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData); 
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
        postStream.Dispose(); 
        myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);

    }
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `TextBox` inputs using the `Text` property.
Assuming you have two `TextBox`es names tb1 and tb2, it should be like this:

```
string postData = "id=" + tb1.Text + "&keyword=otp&message=" + tb2.Text;
```

Comment: I've used the above code but still I'm unable to post the request to my server.

Comment: just saying, I guess you also need to encode that data properly

Comment: I am passing integer in both the text boxes. I am now able to get the response after converting the string to integer.